# Why does sourcetree automatically overwrites branch name?

Tags: git, sourcetree

I'm trying to create a branch, but when i'm trying to do that sourcetree automatically adds it a space and current branch's name.

For example i'm in the `master` branch and want to create a `develop` branch its looks like this:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Did you alias master to develop instead of creating a branch?

Comment: Doesn't it just mean that the two branches still point to the same commit?

Comment: @Caramiriel no. it was a clear creating branch result

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sourcetree is just showing you that the heads of `develop` and `master` are at the same point.

If you were to make a commit (i.e. if you made `develop` and `master` diverge), then you would see the two labels on two different commits.

Comment: I dont think thats true because, when i try to checkout develop source tree doesnt know what the current branch is.

Comment: "...source tree doesn't know"? Does it give you an error?

Comment: @JakeHenningsgaard no it doesnt, i mean it doesnt mark the current branch with dot icon either.

Comment: @kyur are you able to make a commit? can you please try that and report back?

Comment: @yes it tries to push origin with space. like `develop master`

Comment: @kyur can you run `git branch -a` in a terminal from your local repo directory and give your results?